# Why display Queue function in this code printing only first inserted value several times?

Tags: c++, queue

I am learning implementing queue data structure using linked list. Here is my code. Why this display function only printing the first inserted element. And one more doubt is that, I saw some code in geeks for geeks, in that there is a separate queue structure also there. I am thinking that just a single linked list kind of implementation is fine by adding at end and deleting at front. Is there any wrong in this?
Here is my code.

`#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define memory (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue))
using namespace std;
struct queue{
    int data;
    struct queue *next;
};
struct queue *front=NULL, *rear=NULL;
class constructQ{
    public:
        void enQ(int num){
            struct queue *newnode= memory;
            newnode->data= num;
            newnode->next= NULL;
            if(!rear){
               rear=newnode;
                if(!front) front= newnode;
                } 
            else{
                rear->next= newnode;
                rear= newnode;
            }
        }
        void display(){
            struct queue *tmp= front;
            while(tmp){
                cout << front->data << " ";
                tmp= tmp->next;
            }
        }
};

int main(){
    int num, choice;
    constructQ q;
    while(1){
        cout << "1.enqueue  2.Dequeue 3.display 4.exit" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                cin>> num;
                q.enQ(num);
                break;
            case 3:
                q.display();
                break;
            case 4:
                exit(0);
            default:
                cout << "invalid input" << endl;
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}`

Comment: `cout << front->data << " ";`, don't you mean `cout << tmp->data << " ";`?

Comment: `struct queue *tmp` is a "C-ism". In C++ you can write `queue *tmp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Only the first (front) node is being printed is due to the code being:

   `cout << front->data << " "; // prints the front value every iteration`

in the while loop instead of:

```
cout << tmp->data << " " // prints the data in tmp which is the next in every iteration;
```

2. Linked lists can be used to implement Queues and Stacks. The STL uses double-linked lists to allow reverse iteration.

NOTE: It's advisable to use `nullptr` for null pointers instead of NULL (less error prone).

Comment: first, problem solved. And the second part of my question is that queue implementation using linked list. at this link    http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-set-2-linked-list-implementation/     uses two type of structures and why CreateQueue all these things? I am confusing with this code. You can see my implementation in my question above. That type is fine or not? I am just learning please explain.

Comment: First of all the implementation there is in C and not in C++, so there are no classes. Maybe that was a cause of confusion.

Comment: To answer your question regarding the 2 structures: Yes, that is usually how you would implement a data structure: Dividing to a data container (Node) and a Nodes container (Linked List/Binary Tree etc)